# Verb meaning "to present a fact/the facts"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I need a verb meaning "to present a fact/the facts".

E.g. "If you cannot lie you must ***word here***".

I know using multiple words is easy but I need it to be one word.

I do not mean "to speak honestly" because that is too vague and unlike this word, it would not fit.

E.g.

- If someone asks "How many people watched the 1966 FIFA World Cup Final: England v West Germany?"
- If you said "I don't know." you would be speaking honestly but you would not be presenting the "truth/facts" about it.
- If you said "32.80 million rounding to the nearest 10,000. You would be presenting the facts"

Comment: Is this only in a legal/courtroom setting?

Comment: I'm more familiar with contexts where a judge instructs a witness to *stick to answering those questions actually put to him*, rather than "telling everything".

Comment: No that was just an example. This should work anywhere.

Comment: "be honest" fits your example. But I don't really know what you are looking for.

Comment: "Be honest" is two words

Comment: "I know using multiple words is easy but I need it to be one word" is 15 words. We absolutely need it to be 1 word. (For reasons we can't specify in a single word, so I won't specify them at all.) Please rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: @RegDwigнt What do you mean? Your sentences are all confusing. Your first sentence just states the word count, your second sentence says "we" needs it to be one word, who is "we"? Then you have a bracketed sentence which seems like it doesn't belong. Finished by "Please rephrase your question accordingly", according to what?

Answer (score 3):

According to [dictionarydotcom](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mistruths) it doesn't exist as a single verb.

> truth
>
> Meaning "accuracy, correctness" is from 1560s. Unlike lie (v.), there
>   is no primary verb in English or most other IE languages for "speak
>   the truth." Noun sense of "something that is true" is first recorded
>   mid-14c.

But [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truth) lists an obsolete version and the non standard meaning in the lyrics 'you keep lying when you ought to be truthing'.

> Verb
>
> truth (third-person singular simple present truths, present participle
>   truthing, simple past and past participle truthed)
>
> ```
> (obsolete, transitive) To assert as true; to declare; to speak truthfully.
>
>     Had they [the ancients] dreamt this, they would have truthed it heaven. — Ford.
>
> To make exact; to correct for inaccuracy.
>
>     ground truth
>
> (nonstandard, intransitive) To tell the truth.
>
>     1966, You keep lying, when you oughta be truthin' — Nancy Sinatra, "These Boots Are Made for Walkin'"
> ```

Comment: I'm familiar with truthing and lying from the Nancy Sinatra song, I don't know whether it's a 70s thing, or an even older use. I've checked Free Dictionary, OLO, and Merriam-Webster, and yeah I didn't find a verb use listed, which sounds like what you said that it's obsolete, or a funny use.